# javascript click a button using a script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

I would like to click a button using javascript without physically clicking on the bottom.

Below is what I have tried:

```
<li id="#attendBtn"><a style="background:#FF6400;" href="#attend"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Attend</a></li>



echo "<script>            
document.getElementById('attendBtn').click();
</script>";
```

but it does not seem to work. any help would be appreciated

Comment: The ID is on the <li> tag, so you are trying to click the <li> tag, not the <a> tag. Could that be your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `#` in `<li id="#attendBtn">`.

```js
document.getElementById('attendBtn').click();
```

```html
<li id="attendBtn" onclick="console.log(1);"><a style="background:#FF6400;" href="#attend"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Attend</a></li>
```

In `javascript`, if you use `getElementById`, you only need to pass the `id` name. Other frameworks such as `jQuery` use the `#` as an alias to `id`

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById('attendBtn').onclick();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to trigger the click event without actually having to click on the button?
You should look into using jQuery for that then.

Then you can do this:

```
$('#attendBtn').click(function() {
    console.log('button was clicked');
});
```

And trigger it with this:

```
$('#attendBtn').trigger('click');
```

Also, I'm guessing the rest of the html is not posted, as an 'li' should be in a 'ul'?